PBI: External application to visualise and modify the Power BI report.json file
I am going by memory and trying to find an application that I found in December 2023 and can't track it down, but it was a really neat application that you could install locally (so no online applications) that was specifically designed for the power bi report.json file (so no Dax studio, tabular editor, alm toolkit). It was called something like Report Editor or Report Viewer  but basically would load the report.json file and allow you to visualise it from a techinical perspective - i.e. would not load the data but the underlying schema and json data.
I would really appreciate if you are aware of this application that you share it with me. I came across it in a newsletter that I was subscribed to at a previous employer so I can't access it again.
If you have any other cool power bi related software - outside of the 5 external apps that MS list I would be keen to check them out - but please add as a comment and not as a solution.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried searching ms copilot and after several hours it keeps explaining external applications and giving me online applications to edit all json files. This one is specifically and exclusively for the report.json and is a downloadable application.

Do you mean PowerBI Helper which you can get here?
https://powerbihelper.org/

Hi David - I love your work, especially in the custom visualisation space. I have often thought to look you up and share my appreciation of your invaluable contributions to power bi, so thank you for all you have done for us as a community. Unfortunately, no - it's a different app. I focuses specifically on the report.json file and unpacks it into an applcation, I wish I could find it again, it's an incredible tool.

I would like to add that Power BI Helper is awesome for it's documentation capabilities and I have used it extensively for that. I would highly recommend it as an application. Is there a good source of external applications dedicated to power bi - microsoft seem to have limited itself to mainly 3 applications - all around the tabular model. Maybe worth starting a thread here where we can keep track of the tools available, what they do and link resources on how to use them. The fact that this tool is out there and for some reason not hitting the charts confirms we need a good reference point.
